# Popup calculator in ASP.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am working on a project they are making imports and exports. I have completed all the things now their requirement is to add a local currency field in the ASP.net C# Form I added, but they are saying when the amount is entered in USD there should be a small button to popup a calculator and do the computation of exchange.

Regards.

Comment: that relates to ASP.Net C# Forms only..

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Also please add your code so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: let me make it clear , brother i need a popup window in my project to make calculation then copy the result and past it in the required text box.
yet i didn't made any code for this.

Comment: do you want popup window only

Comment: yes i want a popup window only that calculate two numbers and insert the result in the required text box. by clicking the ok button

Comment: use bootstrap modal for popup or any other jquery popup library and use currency exchange api

Comment: What, specifically do you have trouble with? Creating the pop up? The calculation? Passing the information back to the original field? At least give us an example of the form to date. Where is the exchange rate coming from? Please read the [help] and take the [tour] to enable us to help you better.

Comment: #Jon P , really thanks for the great Question to know my problem.

What really difficult is for me to create the popup . and then how to organize text two text fields in popup with a button.
and then when a user clicks on a button in the popup the result directly goes to the text field in my page to save.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```js
/**
 * a calculator function used to create instances of simple math calculators
 */
var Calculator = function (el) {
    var input, buttons, input1, input2, operator;
    
    // responsible for getting elements and kicking off events
    function init(el) {
        
        if (el) {
            
           el = $( el );
        } else {
            
            el = $('#calculator');
            if ( el.length < 1 ) {
               return null;
            }
        }
        
        // get our input and our buttons
        input = el.find( '.calculator-input' );
        buttons = el.find( 'a.btn' );
        events();
    }
    
    function events() {
        
        // block user from entering text in input box
        input.on('keydown', function (e) {
            
           // prevent default action
           e.preventDefault();   
        });
        
        // when a button is clicked, cache it and it's value, delegate
        buttons.on('click', function(e) {
           var target = $( this );
           var val = target.text();
            
           delegate( target, val );
            
           // prevent default action
           e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
    
    function delegate ( target, val ) {
        
        // check to see if we are working with an operator
        if ( target.hasClass( 'operator' ) ) {
            
            // see if the first input is set, if not set it
            if ( !input1 ) {
                input1 = input.val();
            }
           
            // if operator is set that means we need to run a calculation
            if ( operator ) {
                
                // first set input2
                input2 = input.val().split(operator)[1];
                
                // run calculation
                calculate();
            }
            
            // set the operator and update the display
            operator = val;
            updateDisplay(val);
           
        // check to see if we are working with the calculate button
        } else if (target.hasClass( 'calculate' ) ) {
              
            // if both inputs are set, run calculation
            if ( input1 && input2 ) {
                
                calculate();
                
            // else if first input is set and an operator is set
            } else if (input1 && operator) {
                
                // set second input and calculate
                input2 = input.val().split(operator)[1];
                calculate();
            }
        } else {
            
            // otherwise add the input to the display
            updateDisplay(val);
        } 
    }
    
    function clearDisplay () {
        
        // clear the display 
        input.val('');   
    }
    
    function updateDisplay (newValue) {
        
        // add our new input to the display
        input.val( input.val() +  newValue );
    }
    
    function calculate () {
     
        // get value for the input
        var val = eval( input1 + operator + input2 );
        
        // assign value to input1
        input1 = val;
        
        // clear display
        clearDisplay();
        
        // update new display
        updateDisplay(val);
        
        input2 = null;
        operator = null;
    }
    
    init(el);
};

var calculator = new Calculator('.calculator');
```

```css
.modal-body {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width:98%;
    
}
.calculator {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba( 51, 51, 51, 0.2 );
}

.calculator .calculator-controls {
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.calculator .calculator-controls .btn {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #eee; 
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba( 51, 51, 51, 0.2 );
    opacity: .8;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.calculator .calculator-controls .btn:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.calculator .calculator-controls .btn:active {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.calculator .calculator-controls .btn.operator {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    color: #0C7BC5;
}

.calculator .calculator-controls .btn.calculate {
    background: #0C7BC5;
    border: 1px solid #0C7BC5;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Calculator in Modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="calculator">
                <input id="inputcalculation" type="text" class="calculator-input form-control" />
                <div class="calculator-controls">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">7</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">8</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">9</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm operator">+</a></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">4</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">5</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">6</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm operator">-</a></div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">1</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">2</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">3</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm operator">*</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">0</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm">.</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm calculate">=</a></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3"><a href="#" class="btn btn-sm operator">/</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="btncalculate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

for example I give id for both input and button

```
<input id="inputcalculation" type="text" class="calculator-input form-control" />

  <button id="btncalculate" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

and you can accept the value of input by button click with use of jquery or javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () { 
$("#btncalculate").onclick(function () {
    var value = $("#inputcalculation").val();
    alert(value);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Udhay Bhai , you are great man . i almost need the same thing but this is the whole calculator i need just three text fields and one button with multiplication.
i will manage it thanks a lot

Comment: Udhay bhai  please give me a brief on the code, where the first java script code goes. where the second and third goes

Comment: Excellent Udhay. Good Job Done :)

Comment: Dear Udhay Bhai  , i have tried this , i put the client side code in the page the them is coming while i don't know where to put the script code. it need other staff in terms of its CSS and Javascript, could you please guide me a bit .

Comment: you can give id for <input id="sumofnumbers" type="text" class="calculator-input form-control" /> and write jquery or javascript code for this.

Comment: otherwise I update small example with this answer you can try that example. If this answer is useful mark as answer